# bouncing images with href links

Tags: javascript

I found this script that I want to use, but cant work out how to add href to images.

[LOCATION OF SCRIPT](http://lloydhassell.brinkster.net/bouncingimages2/)

Or if someone has a better way or solution.
I supose that a way to choose images by div tag's would be a good way, but how?

> EDIT:
>   As requested for future referances, here is the code
>
> BounceImage.js

```
// INITIALIZATION:

imagesDetails = new Array();
bouncingImages2 = new Object();

// CONFIGURATION:

imagesDetails[0] = new Object();
imagesDetails[0].width = 50;
imagesDetails[0].height = 50;
imagesDetails[0].src = 'logo1xMINI.jpg';

imagesDetails[1] = new Object();
imagesDetails[1].width = 40;
imagesDetails[1].height = 40;
imagesDetails[1].src = 'superball.gif';

imagesDetails[2] = new Object();
imagesDetails[2].width = 60;
imagesDetails[2].height = 50;
imagesDetails[2].src = "1.png";

// Template for further images:

   // imagesDetails[3] = new Object();
   // imagesDetails[3].width = ?;
   // imagesDetails[3].height = ?;
   // imagesDetails[3].src = '?';

bouncingImages2.frameRate = 30;
bouncingImages2.minRandomSpeed = 2;
bouncingImages2.maxRandomSpeed = 8;

// MAIN:

bouncingImages2.isLoaded = false;

var winWidth, winHeight;

if (dyn) {
   for (var imageLoop = 0; imageLoop < imagesDetails.length; imageLoop++) imagesDetails[imageLoop].imgObj = loadImg(imagesDetails[imageLoop].src); 
   }

function getWindowDimensions() {
   winWidth = getWinWidth();
   winHeight = getWinHeight();
   }

function loadBouncingImages2() {
   if (dyn && !bouncingImages2.isLoaded) {
      getWindowDimensions();
      for (var layerLoop = 0; layerLoop < imagesDetails.length; layerLoop++) {
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirX = (Math.round(Math.random()) == 0) ? 'left' : 'right';
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirY = (Math.round(Math.random()) == 0) ? 'up' : 'down';
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (winWidth - imagesDetails[layerLoop].width - 1)) + getDocScrollLeft();
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (winHeight - imagesDetails[layerLoop].height - 1)) + getDocScrollTop();
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedX = Math.round(Math.random() * (bouncingImages2.maxRandomSpeed - bouncingImages2.minRandomSpeed)) + bouncingImages2.minRandomSpeed;
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedY = Math.round(Math.random() * (bouncingImages2.maxRandomSpeed - bouncingImages2.minRandomSpeed)) + bouncingImages2.minRandomSpeed;
         imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj = addLayer('bouncingImagesLyr' + layerLoop);
         setLayerSize(imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj,imagesDetails[layerLoop].width,imagesDetails[layerLoop].height);
         setLayerClip(imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj,0,imagesDetails[layerLoop].width,imagesDetails[layerLoop].height,0);
         setLayerHTML(imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj,getImgTag('bouncingImagesImg' + layerLoop,imagesDetails[layerLoop].src,imagesDetails[layerLoop].width,imagesDetails[layerLoop].height,0));
         moveLayerTo(imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj,imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX,imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY);
         showLayer(imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj);
         }
      bouncingImages2.isLoaded = true;
      moveBouncingImages();
      }
   }

function moveBouncingImages() {
   for (var layerLoop = 0; layerLoop < imagesDetails.length; layerLoop++) {
      if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirX == 'left') {
         if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX > imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedX) imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX -= imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedX;
         else {
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirX = 'right';
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX = 0;
            }
         }
      else if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirX == 'right') {
         if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX + imagesDetails[layerLoop].width < winWidth - imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedX) imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX += imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedX;
         else {
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirX = 'left';
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX = winWidth - imagesDetails[layerLoop].width;
            }
         }
      if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirY == 'up') {
         if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY > imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedY) imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY -= imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedY;
         else {
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirY = 'down';
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY = 0;
            }
         }
      else if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirY == 'down') {
         if (imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY + imagesDetails[layerLoop].height < winHeight -     imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedY) imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY += imagesDetails[layerLoop].speedY;
         else {
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].dirY = 'up';
            imagesDetails[layerLoop].posY = winHeight - imagesDetails[layerLoop].height;
            }
         }
      }
   for (var layerLoop = 0; layerLoop < imagesDetails.length; layerLoop++) moveLayerTo(imagesDetails    [layerLoop].layerObj,imagesDetails[layerLoop].posX + getDocScrollLeft(),imagesDetails    [layerLoop].posY + getDocScrollTop());
   window.setTimeout('moveBouncingImages()',bouncingImages2.frameRate);
   }

window.onresize = getWindowDimensions;
window.onload = loadBouncingImages2;
```

> lib.js is too long for here

In body tag

```
<body onLoad="javascript:loadBouncingImages2();">
```

Comment: you must include code in your questions, external sites can go down, or go away, thus making your questions useless for the rest of the world. External websites are ok, as long as your question makes sense even if the external website cannot or is not accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a trivial old obtrusive script.

**general solution**

In function `loadBouncingImages2()` find where `setLayerHTML()` is called and change its second parameter to whatever HTML string you need.

It could be altered to `'<a href="...">'+getImgTag(...)+'</a>'`.

**universal solution**

replace the setLayerHTML call to

```
var img = getImgTag('bouncingImagesImg' + layerLoop,imagesDetails[layerLoop].src,imagesDetails[layerLoop].width,imagesDetails[layerLoop].height,0);
setLayerHTML(imagesDetails[layerLoop].layerObj,'<a href="'+imagesDetails[layerLoop].href+'">'+img+'</a>');
```

and after that, just modify the configuration by adding `href` to imageDetails, like

```
imagesDetails[0].href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Might be old, but it was what I found and had what I wanted.    
It worked, thanks.    
I am open to better ways and sympler one's as well, but not much out there that I could find.

Comment: While you enhance the bouncing ball script, you could apply some modern patterns on it: they enable better orientation than in one big ball of code: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html Good luck, enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

All your images's containers `id`s start with `bouncingImagesLyr` and the images `name` attribute starts with `bouncingImagesImg` - you can get them using any of this info and then add the classes to them.